# video record with camera intent to byte[]

Tags: android, arrays, fileoutputstream

I have a camera record intent, when the result is ok, i try to convert this video to byte[] to send a webservice:

Im doing this:

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // Video guardado
                    videoUri = data.getData();
                    if (videoUri != null) {

                        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        FileInputStream fichero_codificar = null;
                        try {

                            fichero_codificar = new FileInputStream(
                                    videoUri.getPath());

                            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                            int n;
                            while (-1 != (n = fichero_codificar.read(buf))) {
                                out.write(buf, 0, n);
                            }
                            byte[] videoByte = out.toByteArray();
                            strBase64 = Base64.encode(videoByte);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

But in fichero_codificar = new FileInputStream(
                                        videoUri.getPath())

logcat say me the file is not exists or the patch isnt propertly.

Anyone have a example for my qustion please?
thanks

Comment: Have you verified that videoUri is actually a file (file: prefix) and not a "content:" URI?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're finding the information incorrectly.  Here is how I used the Camera intent in my application:

```
                thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  
            try {

                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(getPicName(index));
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

So maybe try something along those lines with a Video object rather than a Bitmap object.  <s>If that doesn't work, you could try .getAbsolutePath() instead.</s>

Yeah it's definitely not doing what you think it does.  I ran the debugger on mine and getPath returned this: `/external/images/media/21` , which is a content Uri.

Comment: and how can i get a file from a content uri?